# Running Multiple scripts and process Docker

Tags: python, dockerfile

Currently I dockerized my small python app , seems the multiple process does not run in parallel or simultenously.

When running the app without docker, I can simply open two terminal and run each of them.In docker how to accomplish it ?

runner.sh

```
  #!/bin/bash

  exec python3 cron.py //using from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

  exec gunicorn -k eventlet -w 1 app:app -b :8082 // using python socketio
```

Dockerfile

```
  COPY runner_script.sh runner_script.sh
  RUN ["chmod", "+x", "runner_script.sh"]
  CMD ./runner_script.sh
```

But it seems only the first process will only be run.

Comment: have you tried running the runner.sh file in a terminal?

Comment: @CryptoFool if you move your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it as an answer

Comment: Ok, I'll do that.  I'm glad I was able to be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Docker. You'd get the same behavior if you ran this script on your local workstation. You don't want to use exec. Your use of that is why the second command never runs. If you take out the exec keywords, both of your commands should run, one after the other. If you want to run them simultaneously, then you can add an & at the end of the first command to run it in the background.